# How to set Date validation minimum to 3months in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to set minimum date to 3months for expiry date in .net.
The expiry date should be minimum compared to manufacturer date
E.g manufacturer date is 10/10/2019 and expiry date 10/1/2019 ..minimum 3months
Please help me out soon .

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
DateTime manuDate = new DateTime(2019,10,10);
DateTime expireDate = manuDate.AddMonths(3);
```